# Calculate the discrete probability density of $Z=XY$

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent aleatory variables. 
 
$X$ : Poisson with 1 such as parameter 
$Y$ : Bernoulli with $\frac{1}{2}$ such as parameter 

 
Calculate the discrete probability density of  $Z=XY$ 
$$P(Z=0)=P(\{X=0\} \cup \{Y=0\})= \\=P(X=0)+P(Y=0)-P(X=0, Y=0)=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2e}=\frac{e+1}{2e} \\ \\ 
\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}, P(Z=n)=P(X=n, Y=1)=\frac{1}{2 \ e \ n!}  $$

Is it correct?

Comment: The calculations are correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks!

Comment: You  are welcome. Clearly written.

Comment: Just a passerby here, what does $\mathbb{N}^*$ mean?

Comment: @taninamdar From context it is meant to be the non-zero natural numbers, more usually denoted as $\Bbb Z^+$ or $\Bbb N^+$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a confirmation by simulation of a million realizations of $Z$.

```
m = 10^6
x =  rpois(m, 1);  y = rbinom(m, 1, 1/2)
z = x*y
```

The histogram below is based on the simulated values. Dots atop
histogram bars are based on your correct computation of the PDF.
When simulation is this easy, it can provide a quick check
on the accuracy of an analytic result.

[image]